# Excel macro - write data from formula into cells when pushing button

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This is my first post here, so any constructive criticism of my formulation/questions/other is appreciated.

At work we're using excel for planning our year.

Every worker has got an excel sheet with their customer portfolio in them and the hours they've assigned to them.
Besides this we've got a HUGE sheet, with all the customers in them and every coworkers hours, from their sheets.
An attempt to secure that no clients are forgotten and a tool to secure everyone has enough hours to do.

I'm trying to find a way to make these work together, instead of manual input, only validated by a total at the end of each coworkers row and a total in their personal sheets.

I've tried using a lookup in the big sheet, so that when customer number 123 is in my sheet, my hours will get put into my row in the big sheet.

Problem is this makes the huge sheet, even bigger and slower, since it's heavy to do 200.000 looksups i guess.

My thought was to make a button, which would trigger the lookup for a coworkers row of hours to update, so they can update on demand, but not every time the sheet opens.

It's not convenient for the whole sheet to be manual calculated, but if there was a way to only make some cells manually calculated, it would be great, i haven't found any trace of such option though.

I hope someone got an idea on how to do this or maybe something even smarter.

Regards, Kim

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your question is really too broad for this site.  Try reading the guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  As far as "Can this be done", the answer is yes, try writing some code then come back once you have a problem

Comment: What size is HUGE?  What lookups have you tried?

Comment: You could look at the worksheet_change event also, and have calculation manual, then calculate the corresponding etc, so calculate the lookup cell for the total perhaps each time a change is made

Answer (score 0):

You might calculate your values in VBA instead of in a formula within the sheet. This reduces the transparency within the workbook, though.

Then you can use the worksheet_change event to trigger the calculation of the changed row.